ADF copying data form ADLS GEN 2 to Azure SQL Database, Input Payload is invalid error
I am trying to copy data from ADLS GEN2, to Azure SQL Database/SQL Server, connectivity is fine with the LinkedServices, I have checked it. But when I start the Debugging the pipeline I get below error. I have tried a lot, but nothing works.

Input Payload is invalid, validation result - '["Connector or activity name: ADLS_GEN2_SCA, connector or activity type: AzureBlobFS, error: Calling partner RP EvaluatePolicyAsync returned an invalid status code 'Conflict', ReasonPhrase Conflict","Connector or activity name: AzureSqlDatabaseScalez, connector or activity type: AzureSqlDatabase, error: Calling partner RP EvaluatePolicyAsync returned an invalid status code 'Conflict', ReasonPhrase Conflict"]'


Could you please provide configuration of both linked services?


Input Payload is invalid. Validation result: '["Connector or activity name: ADLS_GEN2_SCA, connector or activity type: AzureBlobFS, error: Calling partner RP EvaluatePolicyAsync returned an invalid status code 'Conflict', ReasonPhrase: Conflict","Connector or activity name: AzureSqlDatabaseScalez, connector or activity type: AzureSqlDatabase, error: Calling partner RP EvaluatePolicyAsync returned an invalid status code 'Conflict', ReasonPhrase: Conflict"]'

According to this, check the following things to resolve the above error:

Check the Azure account permissions: Ensure that the account you are using to authenticate to Azure has the necessary permissions to access the resources you are trying to connect to.

Check the Azure Data Factory permissions: Ensure that the service principal or user account that is used to authenticate to Azure Data Factory has the necessary permissions to access the resources you are trying to connect to.

Check the Azure Data Factory linked service settings: Ensure that the linked service settings for the data source you are trying to connect to are correct and that they match the settings for the data source.

Check the Azure Data Factory activity settings: Ensure that the activity settings for the activity you are trying to run are correct and that they meet the requirements of the data source.


Below is the pipeline JSON to copy data from a CSV file in ADLS Gen2 to an SQL database:
{
    "name": "pipeline7",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                        "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                        "disableMetricsCollection": false
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}


@shzyincu Check if below/above provided solution works for you?
